# JQ. tabs() - переключаться, если форма сохранена.

Tags: jquery

Есть во вкладках от JQ формы, при этом открыты несколько вкладок.

Вопрос: как сделать, так чтобы при переключении между вкладками, активная вкладка запросила сохранение формы на сервере, а потом переключилась на выбранную вкладку.

Но можно пропустить этот вопрос и решить такую:
как сделать, чтобы при переключении между вкладками, выбранная вкладка не перезагружалась?

Динамически созданная вкладки при переключении между ними перезагружают содержимое. Поэтому, чтобы введенные данные в формы, чтобы не терялись, их либо надо сохранять, либо не перезагружать вкладку.

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален...

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта:

1. посмотрев сгенерированный код, навесьте на переключатели вкладок дополнительные события.
2. напишите свой табинатор. Это не так сложно, правда. =)

**Добавлено**
Чем пользовался я:

```
function tabify(labels, tabs, start){
    labels = $(labels);
    tabs = $(tabs);
    start = ~~start || 0;
    labels.hide().each(function(i, el){
        var link = $('<a href="#" class="tab"><span><span>'+this.innerHTML+'</span></span></a>');
        link.click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.tab').removeClass('curtab');
            $(this).addClass('curtab');
            tabs.hide().eq(i).show();
            return false;
        });
        if(i == start){
            link.addClass('curtab');
        }
        labels.eq(0).before(link);
    });
    tabs.hide().eq(start).show();
}
```

Пример:

```
<div id="tabber">
    <h3>Заголовок1</h3>
    <table>...</table>
    <h3>Заголовок2</h3>
    <table>...</table>
    <h3>Заголовок3</h3>
    <table>...</table>
</div>

<script>tabify('#tabber h3', '#tabber table')</script>
```

Comment: Самому написать... для меня сложно)) я не шарю в JS)))

Comment: Добавил к ответу.

Comment: Попробую прикрутить... проект на стадии завершения, но попробую... всеже никак не сделать, чтобы табы не перезагружались при переходе между ними?

Причем, перезагрузка происходит, когда таба создана динамически, а "физические" не перезагружаются.

Comment: Вот если честно, не знаю, ни разу не пользовался.